# an Error in Google Translation Api V2

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Last night I wanted to start a new project, but with a strange Error I face !!!
If anyone has worked with Translation API, please help!

The Error Tip is : 
**The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.**

and My Codes are  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG0gj.jpg) too.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TranslationClient cli = TranslationClient.Create();
        var word = cli.TranslateText("hello","fa");
        MessageBox.Show(word.TranslatedText.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: copy paste your code istead of giving screenshot

Comment: what about now???